# Jquery - Select All checkbox nearest to selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below to check All checkboxes inside "select-course-wrapper" div container.

if "business-management-select-all" checked, it have to select all checkboxes inside "select-course-wrapper". Uncheck means, uncheck all checkboxes within this container.

if "chemical-life-science-select-all" checked, it have to select all checkboxes inside "select-course-wrapper". Uncheck means, uncheck all checkboxes within this container.

```js
$('.Checkbox input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ 
                           $(this).parent().closest('.select-course-wrapper').find(':checkbox').prop("checked", true);
                      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group accordion-check">
   <div class="Checkbox">
      <input id="business-management-select-all" name="business-management-select-all" type="checkbox"> 
      <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-txt">Select all</div>
   <div class="select-course-wrapper">
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="business-management-accounting" name="business-management-accounting" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Accounting</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="business-management-brand-management" name="business-management-brand-management" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Brand Management</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group accordion-check">
   <div class="Checkbox">
      <input id="chemical-life-science-select-all" name="chemical-life-science-select-all" type="checkbox"> 
      <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-txt">Select all</div>
   <div class="select-course-wrapper">
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-accounting" name="chemical-life-science-accounting" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Accounting</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-brand-management" name="chemical-life-science-brand-management" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Brand Management</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-business-communications" name="chemical-life-science-business-communications" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Business Communications</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's your question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test if the `$(".Checkbox input[type='checkbox']")` than check or uncheck the other boxes based on its value, also you need to add `.parent()` you were looking inside the wrong div.

Try this:

```js
$(".Checkbox input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){ 
  if (this.checked )
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".select-course-wrapper input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
  else
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".select-course-wrapper input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group accordion-check">
   <div class="Checkbox">
      <input id="business-management-select-all" name="business-management-select-all" type="checkbox"> 
      <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-txt">Select all</div>
   <div class="select-course-wrapper">
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="business-management-accounting" name="business-management-accounting" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Accounting</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="business-management-brand-management" name="business-management-brand-management" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Brand Management</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group accordion-check">
   <div class="Checkbox">
      <input id="chemical-life-science-select-all" name="chemical-life-science-select-all" type="checkbox"> 
      <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox-txt">Select all</div>
   <div class="select-course-wrapper">
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-accounting" name="chemical-life-science-accounting" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Accounting</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-brand-management" name="chemical-life-science-brand-management" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Brand Management</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group accordion-check">
         <div class="Checkbox">
            <input id="chemical-life-science-business-communications" name="chemical-life-science-business-communications" type="checkbox"> 
            <div class="Checkbox-visible"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox-txt">Business Communications</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```